# What is a good way to know mdadm RAID 5 array used size

Tags: software-raid, raid5

I run a mdadm RAID 5 array of 4 3TB disks on Ubuntu 18.04, with a total size of 9TB. It displays as a 9.0 TB RAID-5 Array in gnome disk utilities, and the usage is 799 GB free, which means I have over 8T data.

I then bought a NAS and start copying data from RAID to a new disk. The copy was completed after 4 hours with no error. After the copy, the new disk is only 5.2TB used.

When I use gnome-files to count the total number/size of files on the RAID-5 array, it shows that the free space is only 498.9 GB, which means I have 9T - 500G = 8.5T data?

I finally use `du` on both the RAID and the nas disk. The result shows both are 4.7T.

Why are there discrepancies and which number is correct?

Comment: Have you copied all the files (not intended as a silly question - please do check!)? What filesystem is on the RAID5 and what filesystem is used on the NAS? Are there a lot of duplicated files (or partially duplicated) files? Or sparse files that weren't written sparsely on the RAID5 volume?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Both the RAID5 and NAS uses ext4, and the number of files in src and dest is the same. There can be many duplicated files because I use the RAID 5 as a backup. There are chances that I forgot some files are already in the RAID, and backed it up again. There are no sparse files as far as I know. (most files are DVD images, PDFs and video files).

Comment: If your RAID 5 was actually either RAID 6 or RAID 10 the numbers would work

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. It shows "RAID-5 Array 9TB" in the disk utilities. However, this reminds me. Originally I built the array as 3 3TB disks and then later add one more disk. But I do not remember if I executed `mdadm grow` or not back then. If I forgot to do `mdadm grow`, is it possible the array is displayed as 9TB, but actually is only 6 TB? If so, that explains the discrepancy.

Comment: Please add `cat /proc/mdstat` to your question

Comment: Just arrived home. `cat /proc/mdstat` shows only three disks. That's why. Thanks for the help. However, I still did not understand why `gnome-disk-utility` shows it as '9.0 TB RAID-5 Array'. Does it simply just add up all disk capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [turns out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679662/what-is-a-good-way-to-know-mdadm-raid-5-array-used-size?noredirect=1#comment1284035_679662) that the RAID subsystem has actually got only three disks instead of four. 3x 3TB in RAID5 gives 6TB usable space, and now the numbers add up and match as expected.

This can be seen with the command line utilities

```
cat /proc/mdstat          # display the makeup of the RAID arrays
df /path/to/mountpoint    # show disk used/free/available for the filesystem
```